# How can I dynamically add items into paper-dropdown-menu?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I tried adding it with like dropdownMenu.appendChild(menuItem) but as I expected this doesn't work. I couldn't find information about this on Polymer's guides nor other similar questions on here.

Is that possible? If so, how?

paper-dropdown-menu: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 6):

In Polymer, recommended way of manipulating the DOM is by manipulating the data:

- put the list of menu items in array: `var items_array = [....];`

-create the menu as:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items_array}}">
      <paper-item>{{item}}</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

- adding and removing elements in `items_array` will affect the menu immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Found out the proper way from their [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api):

Should select the Polymer element with: `Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector(selector)`

And append with: `Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(node)`