# Polymer 1.x Remove Element By Variable Reference

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element that is being injected and stored using the following line:

```
this._lastPromo = this.$$('#inject-point').appendChild(promo);
```

I now need to remove this element at a later time in my codebase.I have tried the following 2 scenarios:

```
this.$$('#inject-point').removeChild(this._lastPromo);
```

And:

```
this._lastPromo.parentNode.removeChild(this._lastPromo);
```

I get the following errors:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is
>   not a child of this node.

And:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Question:
**How can I remove this specific element from the document?**

Comment: That code looks good, can you provide some more code or a JS Bin so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Probably you have specific situation, but just to mention that in Polymer recommended way of manipulating the DOM is by manipulating the data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38950936/986212

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I discovered that `this.$$('#inject-point').appendChild(promo);` only returns the newly created DOM object but it does not retain references to it's position in the DOM.

The parent is not recorded on the Object.

To work around the issue I stored the new DOM Object into a property before I inject it into the DOM and then later remove it like so:

```
Polymer.dom(this._lastPromoEl).parentNode.removeChild(this._lastPromoEl);
```